# How to apply Java lambda expression filtering in Grails

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, grails, grails-orm

I already wrote few code for my spring mvc controller for fetching employee attendance record from a single column from my table using lambda expression filter.
But I want to apply the same logic in my Grails Controller.

Take a look into[image: screen] scree.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

In your case the straight-forward way to iterate the same collection 4 (!!!) times and spawn 4 new collections is also the least performant one.

I'd put it like this:

```
import static Constant.*

def data = presentMonthAtten.inject( [:].withDefault{ 0 } ){ accum, record ->
  switch( record.status ){
    case ABSENT: accum.absent++; break
    case PRESENT: accum.present++; break
    // other cases
  }
  accum
}

//....
attendDashBoard.currentMonthAbsentAttn = data.absent.toString()
```

Comment: Wow..I am gonna implement this, If I will face any problem I will let you know and just guide me.

Comment: here I am getting Exception, No such property: materialStatus for class: java.lang.String===    poStatus = PurchaseOrder.executeQuery('select materialStatus from PurchaseOrder')

        def data = poStatus.inject( [:].withDefault{ 0 } ){ accum, record ->
            switch( record.materialStatus ){, In my purchase order calss there is variable materialStatus.

Comment: you are trying to access the property `materialStatus` on String object. Looks like you should use `switch( record ){ ... }`

Comment: Hi @injecteer please check this link and if its possible please help me. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38443269/how-to-get-top-five-highest-value-in-descending-order-using-grails

Answer (score 1):

if I understand it correctly (counting the records), you could try something like:

```
long totalAbsentDays 
= presentMonthAtten.findAll{ it.status == Constant.ABSENT }.size()
```

Comment: Seems to fine but what is the meaning "it" after curly braces ?

Comment: it's the default iterator variable, which is automatically available. You could also define the name of the iterator variable by yourself via 'presentMonthAtten.findAll{ record -> record.status == Constant.ABSENT }.size()'

Comment: Well I will implement it and let you know about it.